# Postgres calling Function in functio does not what I expect

Tags: postgresql, function

**Hi, 
the function F_B() returns in bracket "(i,m)" instead of 2 columns "i" and "m"!**

```
CREATE FUNCTION F_A
(
i_productionsitename IN TEXT, 
i_printjobid IN TEXT,
i_isnewlycreated IN INT,
o_returncode OUT TEXT, 
o_message OUT TEXT
) AS $$
DECLARE 

BEGIN 
    Select 'i', 'm'  into o_ReturnCode, o_message;
    END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

SELECT * FROM F_A('DRM', '42',1);
=>   i   & m

```
CREATE FUNCTION  F_B

    (
        i_productionsitename IN TEXT, 
        i_printjobid IN TEXT,
        i_isnewlycreated IN INT,
        o_returncode OUT TEXT, 
        o_message OUT TEXT
    ) AS $$
DECLARE 
    rec RECORD;
    l_ReturnCode TEXT;
    l_Message    TEXT;

    BEGIN
        o_ReturnCode      := 'l_OK'; 
        o_Message         := 'l_Kein Problem';

        Select F_A (i_ProductionSiteName, i_PrintJobID , i_isnewlycreated)  INTO l_ReturnCode, l_Message ; --rec ;
        o_ReturnCode := l_ReturnCode; --' rec.o_message;
        o_Message := l_Message;

        END;

    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
    SELECT * FROM F_B('DRM', '42',1);
```

=> gives (i,m) & null

Why is second column empty, but first has the 2 values?
What is wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Try `Select * FROM F_A (i_ProductionSiteName, i_PrintJobID , i_isnewlycreated) INTO...` . You are selecting the result from F_A into a record instead of two individual values.

Comment: Yes Cool.
So easy but so hard to find!
Thanks a lot